# polymer V1.0 iron-list in a complex flex layout is not visible

Tags: polymer

I'm playing with Google's Polymer library and I have trouble with iron-list in a (complex) flex layout. The list is not rendered.

Here is my HTML:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>

    <title>iron-list and flex layout</title>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, minimum-scale=1.0, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=yes">
    <meta name="mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:900">

    <script src="bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.js"></script>

    <link rel="import" href="bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">
    <link rel="import" href="bower_components/iron-flex-layout/iron-flex-layout.html">
    <!--<link rel="import" href="bower_components/iron-flex-layout/classes/iron-flex-layout.html">-->
    <!--<link rel="import" href="bower_components/iron-flex-layout/classes/iron-shadow-flex-layout.html">-->
    <link rel="import" href="bower_components/paper-toolbar/paper-toolbar.html">
    <link rel="import" href="bower_components/paper-scroll-header-panel/paper-scroll-header-panel.html">
    <link rel="import" href="bower_components/paper-tabs/paper-tabs.html">
    <link rel="import" href="bower_components/paper-tabs/paper-tab.html">
    <link rel="import" href="bower_components/paper-icon-button/paper-icon-button.html">
    <link rel="import" href="bower_components/paper-button/paper-button.html">
    <link rel="import" href="bower_components/paper-input/paper-input.html">
    <link rel="import" href="bower_components/iron-ajax/iron-ajax.html">
    <link rel="import" href="bower_components/iron-icons/iron-icons.html">

    <link rel="import" href="bower_components/iron-list/iron-list.html">

    <style is="custom-style">
        * {font-family: Roboto}
        body, html {width:100%;height:100%;margin:0;padding:0;border:0;overflow-y: hidden;}
        .header {height: 50px;}
        .footer {height: 30px;}
        .header-bg {background: #f4f4f4;}
    </style>
</head>
<body unresolved class="flex vertical layout self-stretch">

<template is="dom-bind">

    <iron-ajax id="get_filltext_ajax" auto
               url="//www.filltext.com/"
               params='{"rows": "100", "fname":"{firstName}", "lname": "{lastName}", "address": "{streetAddress}",
                       "city": "{city}", "state": "{usState|abb}", "zip": "{zip}", "integer": "{number|100}",
                       "business": "{business}", "index": "{index}"}'
               handle-as="json"
               loading="{{loading}}"
               last-response="{{people}}">
    </iron-ajax>

   <div class="header header-bg">header</div>

    <div class="vertical layout flex">
        <div class="horizontal layout ">
            <div class="flex header-bg">header left</div>
            <div class="flex header-bg">header right</div>
        </div>

        <div class="horizontal layout flex self-stretch">
            <div class="flex horizontal layout" style="border: solid 2px #00e034;">
                <!-- content left-->

                <!--<iron-list items="[[people]]" as="item" style="height:500px;width:300px;">-->
                <iron-list items="[[people]]" as="item" class="self-stretch">
                    <template>
                        <div>
                            <div class="item">
                                <div class="primary dim">[[item.index]]</div>
                                <div class="pad">
                                    <div class="primary"><span>[[item.fname]]</span> <span>[[item.lname]]</span></div>
                                    <div class="secondary"><span>[[item.address]]</span> <span>[[item.city]]</span></div>
                                    <div class="secondary"><span>[[item.city]]</span>, <span>[[item.state]]</span>  <span>[[item.zip]]</span></div>
                                    <div class="secondary dim">[[item.business]]</div>
                                </div>
                                <iron-icon icon$="[[iconForItem(item)]]"></iron-icon>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </template>
                </iron-list>

            </div>
            <div class="flex" style="border: solid 2px #e00034;">content right</div>
        </div>

        <div class="horizontal layout header-bg">
            <div class="flex self-end">footer left</div>
            <div class="flex self-end">footer right</div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="footer header-bg">
        <paper-button>Footer</paper-button>
    </div>

</template>

</body>
</html>
```

If the dimension of the iron-list tag is defined, the list will be visible:
    
See: https://goo.gl/photos/yBbM9jtndyAtKiBCA

Green and red (bottom) border of left and right content div is visible.

I tried to set flex and/or self-stretch to the iron-list tag without success.

Desired result: iron-list should use the full width and height of the (red) left content div.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I managed to get an iron-list contained by a polymer element to fill an entire screen/browser sized iron-page section and to scroll within that boundry (i.e. rather than overflowing and causing the section itself to scroll).  The top level html looks like this:

```
<body class="fullbleed layout vertical">
  <iron-pages>
    <section class="layout vertical fit">
      <div>title element that uses a varying amount of space</div>
      <div class="flex">
         <my-list-element/>
      </div>
   </section>
</iron-pages>
</body>
```

The my-list-element looks like this:

```
<dom-module id="my-list-element">
  <style>
    :host {
      display: block;
      height: 100%
    }

    iron-list {
      height: 100%;
    }
  </style>

  <template>
    <iron-list items={{whatever}}>
       <template>
          .... etc ....
       </template>
    </iron-list>
  </template>
</dom-module>
```

This causes the  to fill the screen, and the iron-list scrolls in the div that contains the my-list-template instance.  This is the only way I found to accomplish this. Everything else caused the list to overflow the page and therefore the entire page scrolled (which I didn't want).

The important aspects of this are:

1. The *fit* style on the section.
2. The *flex* style on the div that contains my-list-element.
3. Both 100% *height* styles that you see in the element (on the element itself and on its contained iron-list).

Edit: In Chrome 43 the entire section scrolls.  In Chromium 39 (where I tested original) it scrolled in the div.  Either way, the iron-list is displayed.  I'll update if I sort out how to get it scrolling in the the boundary of flexed div.

Comment: Solved. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Solved (https://goo.gl/photos/J2Ua6phhVrYgLitE6):

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>iron-list and flex layout</title>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, minimum-scale=1.0, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=yes">
    <meta name="mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">

    <script src="bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.js"></script>

    <link rel="import" href="bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">
    <link rel="import" href="bower_components/iron-flex-layout/iron-flex-layout.html">
    <link rel="import" href="bower_components/paper-tabs/paper-tab.html">
    <link rel="import" href="bower_components/iron-list/iron-list.html">
    <link rel="import" href="bower_components/iron-resizable-behavior/iron-resizable-behavior.html">
    <style>
        body, html {width:100%;height:100%;margin:0;padding:0;border:0;overflow-y: hidden;}
        .scrolly {overflow-y: scroll;}
    </style>
</head>
<body class="fullbleed layout vertical">

<dom-module id="my-list-element">
    <style>
        :host {
            display: block;
            height: 100%
        }
        iron-list {
            height: 100%;
        }
    </style>

    <template>
        <iron-list items={{items}}>
            <template>
                <div class="primary dim">[[item.name]]</div>
            </template>
        </iron-list>
    </template>

    <script>
        (function(){
            Polymer({
                is: 'my-list-element',

                properties: {
                    items: {
                        type: Array,
                        value: []
                    }
                },
                ready: function() {
                    console.log('ready list');
                    for (var i=0; i< 100; i++) {
                        this.push('items', {name:'Test item ' + this.items.length });
                    }
                }
            });
        })();
    </script>

</dom-module>


<iron-pages>
    <section class="layout vertical fit">
        <div>title element that uses a varying amount of space<br>second header row</div>
        <div class="horizontal layout ">
            <div class="flex header-bg"><b>header left</b></div>
            <div class="flex header-bg"><b>header right</b></div>
        </div>


        <div class="flex horizontal layout ">
            <div class="flex header-bg scrolly"><my-list-element /></div>
            <div class="flex header-bg scrolly"><my-list-element /></div>
        </div>

        <div class="horizontal layout ">
            <div class="flex header-bg"><b>footer left</b></div>
            <div class="flex header-bg"><b>footer right</b></div>
        </div>
        <div>Footer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31964572/polymer-v1-0-iron-list-in-a-complex-flex-layout-is-not-visible</div>
    </section>
</iron-pages>

</body>
</html>
```